# Headphones for ps4

Tags: ps4, voice-chat

I hope this is the right place to ask a question regarding ps4 headphones.

I bought a ps4 pro and was wondering if regular heaphones are good for using in ps4 games or does it require special ps4 headphones.

Let me know if there is any difference. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any at all, like literally just plug in your earphones and it will work. As long as the device has a proper audio jack it should fit and output sound through it. Plugging earphones/headphones will let sound play through your TV/Moniter and the sound device you plugged in meaning that you don't need to mute people in online games just plug in your earphones and keep them outside of your ears, as VOIP defaults to headset's.